# refrescar una modal en bootstrap sin que se cierre luego de realizar un update

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

tengo una duda segun yo bootstrap tiene una opcion que te refresca su modal luego de una ejecucion como agregar o modificar... asi como el *modal('hide');

```
   success:function(desactivar_contacto)
            {
                if(desactivar_contacto = true)
                {
                    $('#confirmar_eliminar').modal('hide');
            
                }
```

existe alguna manera propia de bootstrap para refrescar o recargar su modal sin tener que cerrarla ??

Comment: Propia de bootstrap lo dudo. Eres tu quien debe cambiar el contenido del modal despues de una ejecución de agregar o modificar, seguramente en javascript (incluye ajax y variantes).  El modal de bootstrap 4 tiene un número determinado de [métodos](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/modal/#methods), y ninguno parece ser un `refresh` del contenido, seguramente porque no controla las acciones que se ejecutan dentro ni su comportamiento ni su nueva salida, si la hay.

Comment: llena el modal con un div que sea el contenido, y luego con js vanilla o con jquery, podes cambiar el .innerHTML o .html() del mismo, como lo harias con cualquier otro div.